# Flowlayout panel not display the scroll bar after some resizes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, user-interface

I have a flowlayout panel and on a resize event, I resize all the controls inside the flowlayout panel so they fit the width of the  (flowlayoutpanel - padding - scroll bar width). On some resizes, the scroll bar is not shown, hiding most of the controls outside the area of the flowlayoutpanel while on other resizes the scroll bar is shown.I have set the AutoScroll property on the flowlayoutpanel to true.  This is all done using C#, but I have also encountered this problem in VB.net.

Is there a way to force the flowlayoutpanel to recalculate how the controls are laid out after I resize the controls in the resize event or some other way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `.PerformLayout()` method, see if that helps.

Comment: That's .PerformLayout() for anyone that misses it :)

Answer (score 1):

By using the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) method (inherited from Control) you can force the control to invalidate and redraw itself and its children.

Edit: Curiously, are you doing this resize to get the effect of top-bottom stacking?